# incompatible types: ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> cannot be converted to List<List<Integer>>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

I am doing a Leetcode question "Binary Tree Zigzag Level Order Traversal" with java.
And I got a compile error

> "incompatible types: ArrayList< ArrayList < Integer>> cannot be
>   converted to List< List < Integer>>".

Anyone can tell me where I was wrong and how should I change the code?
Thank you very much!

The following is my code:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */

public class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> zigzagLevelOrder(TreeNode root) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        if (root == null) return result;

        Stack<TreeNode> currLevel = new Stack<TreeNode>();
        Stack<TreeNode> nextLevel = new Stack<TreeNode>();
        Stack<TreeNode> tmp;

        currLevel.add(root);
        boolean normalOrder = true;

        while(!currLevel.isEmpty()) {
            ArrayList<Integer> currLevelResult = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            while(!currLevel.isEmpty()) {
                TreeNode node = currLevel.pop();
                currLevelResult.add(node.val);
                if (normalOrder) {
                    if(node.left != null) nextLevel.add(node.left);
                    if(node.right != null) nextLevel.add(node.right);
                }
                else {
                    if(node.right != null) nextLevel.add(node.right);
                    if(node.left != null) nextLevel.add(node.left);
                }
            }
            result.add(currLevelResult);
            tmp = currLevel;
            currLevel = nextLevel;
            nextLevel = tmp;
            normalOrder = !normalOrder;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You change `ArrayList<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();`. (Also, `List<Integer> currLevelResult = new ArrayList<>();` is preferable.)

Comment: Hi Sotirios Delimanolis, first of all, thanks for editing my post.

Comment: However, after reading the post "Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?". I am still confused about my question. I thinks my question is different. The arraylist can not be coverted to list. And do you have any idea how should I change my code?

Comment: I would say if u really wanna keep the structure correct it should be public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> zigzagLevelOrder(TreeNode root) {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

To avoid all type safety issue. Basically your return type is same as declared variable type

Comment: @laune Thanks a lot! Problem solved:) One more question, What should I learn more about this? java interface? or linked list basic concept?

Comment: @Yaozhong your question is not very clear both of them are different. Linked List is a data structure type. whereas interface is actually programming usage in java in OOP design pattern. If You will read COllections in java you will realize List, Set, Map these are interfaces for common data structures in java. I will say you need to know data structure concepts and Java OOP both of them individually

Comment: @Acewin Oh I mean I did as laune told me: change to ArrayList<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>(); And it worked. But I don't know why this is correct but mine was wrong. So to understand this, what should I learn? Thank you Acewin

Comment: @laune usage is correct for the compiler because that removes all typecasting thus may not be very correct/useful. As for the answer List<Integer> will be superset of ArrayList<Integer> like how Animal is superset of Dog. Rest I hope you can infer yourself

Comment: @Acewin As the return type is `List<List<Integer>>` you don't need to be more specific in the variable's type where you construct the object to be returned. In fact, you'd be free to mix ArrayLists and LinkedList and whatever else implements List.